# OMPL Plugin for V-Rep

Tags: simulator, motion-planning

I am trying to implement a path planning algorithm in V-Rep. In `Tools -> Calculation Module Properties -> Path Planning`, V-Rep recommends to use the OMPL plugin for path planning. I couldn't find any information (In V-Rep as well as OMPL's websites) regarding where to get the plugin. Where might I get it and how can I use it in V-Rep?

Answer (score 2):

The OMPL plugin is integrated on Vrep, at least in latest versions (>3.3.0), so you doesn't need to download anything.

They sugest some scenarios as example, like the "*motionPlanningDemo1*" or "*scenes/6DoFHolonomicPathPlanning.ttt*".

One basic guide:

1) Create a task, ***simExtOMPL_createTask()***

2) Define the State Space, ***simExtOMPL_createStateSpace()***

3) Associate the State Space to the task previously created, ***simExtOMPL_setStateSpace()***

4) Choose the algorithm you want, ***simExtOMPL_setAlgorithm()***

5) Define the colisions, ***simExtOMPL_setColisionPairs()***

6) Define the inictial state, ***simExtOMPL_setStartState()***

7) Define the final state, ***simExtOMPL_setGoal()***

8) Calculate the path, ***simExtOMPL_compute()***

For documentations about Path Planning using OMPL, please see the chapter *Path and motion planning* on Vrep documentation.